# parentId not getting in a vf controller

Tags: visualforce

```
public with sharing class ZTestPageCtrl {

    public ZTestPageCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        apexpages.addMessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.info,''+controller.getRecord()));
    }

}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ZTestPageCtrl">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

But when i do this same code in different org, I am not getting AccountId. It just displays Contact{} in a vfpage message. I am a system admin in both the org.

Comment: But when i do this same code in different org, I am not getting AccountId. It just displays Contact{} in a vfpage message. I am a system admin in both the org.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the Id of an object in the URL you are viewing/editing and the `StandardController` reads that object and so you will see the sort of output in your screen shot:

```
/apex/YourPageName?Id=001000000000123
```

When you do not include the Id of an object in the URL you are saying you want to create a new (empty and with no Id) object:

```
/apex/YourPageName
```

So make sure the URL in both orgs has a (valid in the org) Id value. (You can find a valid Id by opening the detail page of an Account and taking the value from the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) on the `addFields()` method from the StandardController class:

> When a Visualforce page is loaded, the fields accessible to the page are based on the fields referenced in the Visualforce markup. This method adds a reference to each field specified in fieldNames so that the controller can explicitly access those fields as well.

So, if you want the fields to appear, you have 2 options:

1. Reference them on the visualforce page:

```html
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ZTestPageCtrl">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
</apex:page>
```

2. Use the `addFields` method on the controller.

```java
public with sharing class ZTestPageCtrl {

    public ZTestPageCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        controller.addFields(new List<String>{'AccountId'});
        apexpages.addMessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.info,''+controller.getRecord()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Also. Take a look on Keith's answer

Comment: Hi Fernando,   I have tried all the possible ways that you suggested above earlier before posting this question. But no use. actually I am opening this page from the account related list. contact New button is overridden. so by default i have to get AccountId in a standardController in that constructor. but I am not getting. It causes Issues in sandbox. but same code after deployment is working fine in production. I wonder from this behavior.